# Error message "undefined reference to 'List::a'"

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I am getting the error shown below while linking the code. How can I fix this problem?

It seems the static variable is not getting initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct name{
    char c;
};

class List {
    static name *a;
public:
    static void modify()
    {
        a = new name();
        cout<<"yes";
    }
};

name List::*a = NULL;

int main()
{
    List::modify();
}

g++ O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o sample.o "..\\sample.cpp"
g++ -o sample.exe sample.o
sample.o:sample.cpp:(.text.startup+0x35): undefined reference to `List::a'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5):

`name List::*a = NULL;` doesn't do what you expected. It defines a global variable named `a`, which is a pointer to non-static member of `List` of type `name`.

The definition of `List::a` should be

```
name* List::a = NULL;
```

Comment: Yepp. Here the fixed [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b59ca9b5216387).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. :). The issue is resolved now. I still don't understand why the compiler didn't flagged the same.

Comment: Btw. may be, it's worth to add a note about the IMHO strange usage of `struct name`. It looks like if something else was intended.

Comment: @PriteshVikram Your declaration is valid. It doesn't mean what you thought it meant, but it's still valid.